# How to loop over objects nested in other objects? Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a nested interface that looks like this:

```
interface Main { 
  id: string,
  name: string,
  section: Section[]
}

interface Section {
  name: string,
  subSection: SubSection[]
}

interface SubSection {
  name: string
}
```

Then I have my data:

```
const myData {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'first',
      section: {
        name: 'section',
        subsection: {
          name: 'subsection'
        }
      }
     },
     
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'second',
      section: {
        name: 'section',
        subsection: {
          name: 'subsection'
        }
       }
     }
}
```

So my goal is to display information for each object. I've been told that I need to use nested loops for this, but I'm a complete newbie and have no idea how to do it properly.
Right now I have this:

```
  objects: Main[] = []

    getData() {
    for(const [i, data] of Object.entries(myData)) {
      for(const [i, section] of Object.entries(data['section'])) {
      }

      this.objects.push({
        id: data['id'],
        name: data['name']
      })
     }
    }
```

How do I get my sections and subsections values in this.objects.push?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` and `map` like this: (Note that this snippet is for JavaScript but still works in typescript too)

```js
const myData = {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'first',
      section: {
        name: 'section',
        subsection: {
          name: 'subsection'
        }
      }
     },
     
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'second',
      section: {
        name: 'section',
        subsection: {
          name: 'subsection'
        }
       }
     }
}

let sections = Object.values(myData).map(t=>t.section);
let subsections = sections.map(t=>t.subsection);

console.log('sections', sections);
console.log('subsections', subsections);
```

Comment: @koichi Has your problem been solved? you just need map to select subset of object in your array

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you didn't use your interfaces on `myData` but this is how you could simply iterate over your object and the corresponding `sections` & `subSections`.

Note I applied your `Main`-`interface` using [Index Signature](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/4.4.0-beta/typescript.min.js) to `myData` to be safe when iterating.

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) gives you an `array` of all values of `myData` so you can loop it. The rest is pretty much self-explanatory.

```js
interface Main {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  section: Section[];
}

interface Section {
  name: string;
  subSection: SubSection[];
}

interface SubSection {
  name: string;
}

const myData: {
  [key: number]: Main
} = {
  1: {
    id: "1",
    name: "first",
    section: [{
      name: "section",
      subSection: [{
        name: "subsection1",
      }, ],
    }, ],
  },
  2: {
    id: "2",
    name: "second",
    section: [{
      name: "section",
      subSection: [{
        name: "subsection2",
      }, ],
    }, ],
  },
};

Object.values(myData).forEach((main) =>
  main.section.forEach((section) =>
    section.subSection.forEach((subSection) => console.log(subSection))
  )
);
```